# App wont run after vue `init`

Tags: node.js, vue.js

After a brand new installation of NodeJS and vue-cli in an Ubuntu machine, I create a Vue app with

`vue init webpack-simple frontend`

then cd into `frontend` and run

`npm install`

which downloads a lot of dependencies.

I then run 
`npm run dev`

but get an error with the `css-loader` dependency

```
> frontend@1.0.0 dev /home/pepo/workspace/jiemaps/frontend
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /dist/
404s will fallback to /index.html
loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.
Hash: 1fe5ee39c7e45c04fc58
Version: webpack 2.3.1
Time: 2039ms
                                    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
logo.png?82b9c7a5a3f405032b1db71a25f67021  6.85 kB          [emitted]         
                                 build.js  1.58 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
chunk    {0} build.js (main) 565 kB [entry] [rendered]
   [36] ./~/vue/dist/vue.esm.js 244 kB {0} [built]
   [38] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
   [39] ./src/main.js 134 bytes {0} [built]
   [40] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 5.44 kB {0} [built]
   [41] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.57 kB {0} [built]
   [43] ./~/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
   [52] ./~/punycode/punycode.js 14.7 kB {0} [built]
   [58] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/entry.js 244 bytes {0} [built]
   [84] ./~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
   [86] ./~/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
   [88] ./src/App.vue 1.53 kB {0} [built]
   [94] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.6 kB {0} [built]
   [95] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 856 bytes {0} [built]
   [97] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.02 kB {0} [built]
   [98] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
     + 84 hidden modules

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"id":"data-v-25441132","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:404:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at loadLoader (/home/pepo/workspace/jiemaps/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/pepo/workspace/jiemaps/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/pepo/workspace/jiemaps/frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
 @ ./~/vue-style-loader!./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"id":"data-v-25441132","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 4:14-272 13:3-17:5 14:22-280
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to node7 fixed this problem for me.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/728

my node and vue version:

```
$ vue -V
> 2.8.1

$ node -v
> v6.10.1

$ npm -v
> 3.10.10
```